# tool bar is not pinned to the top and smaller than action bar size in android

Tags: android, android-toolbar

i have the same code in couple of XML files. and in some the tool bar is shown like i want (like an action bar) and in other its smaller and its floating. see photo:
[image]

my tool bar in the screen xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar">
        </include>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

my app_bar xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

styles:

```
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be have padding in root of your AppBarLayout
just remove padding.

Answer (score 0):

```
toolbar parent;
parent.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0, 0);
```

try this!